# Exception in xsl transformation

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have an xsl which defines a javascript function, and is used to transform an incoming xml into html for rendition.

I am facing a peculiar transformation error, which I have been unable to resolve.

```
var srcId='<xsl:value-of select="verify/srcId/text()"/>';
alert("source - " + srcId);

if(flashOption=="N" && srcId===""){
    alert(....);
    return false;
}
```

The `&& srcId` clause is causing the transformation to fail. `(!srcId)` results in the same error too.

If i do remove that particular clause,I see no error and do see `srcId` getting populated with valid values after rendition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersands have special meaning in XML. Escape the `&`'s in the XML code and it should work fine.

```
var srcId='<xsl:value-of select="verify/srcId/text()"/>';
alert("source - " + srcId);

if(flashOption=="N" &amp;&amp; srcId===""){
    alert(....);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I actually resolved by nesting rather than '&&' clause.So did not get time to verify the answer.But this makes sense.